# Send email reply to specific outlook email from python

Tags: python-3.x, email, smtplib

I have added outlook mail parsing functionality in my project. Now i want to reply to specific email using python code.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it. I believe that the "Reply-To" header should be set explicitly. The likely reason is that it's less commonly used than headers such as "Subject", "To", and "From".

```
python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, May 10 2011, 11:07:28) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.domain.com'
>>> TO_ADDRESS = 'you@gmail.com'
>>> FROM_ADDRESS = 'email@domain.com'
>>> REPLY_TO_ADDRESS = 'email2@domain2.com'
>>> import smtplib
>>> import email.mime.multipart
>>> msg = email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart()
>>> msg['to'] = TO_ADDRESS
>>> msg['from'] = FROM_ADDRESS
>>> msg['subject'] = 'testing reply-to header'
>>> msg.add_header('reply-to', REPLY_TO_ADDRESS)
>>> server = smtplib.SMTP(MAIL_SERVER)
>>> server.sendmail(msg['from'], [msg['to']], msg.as_string())
{}
```